# Spring boot: configure it to find the webapp folder

Tags: spring, config

By default, Spring Boot looks in my src/main/webapp folder to find my html files. Where can I change the settings for Spring Boot if I use another folder to put the html files?

Later, the files will be wrapped in jars for deployment. Are there other things I need to worry about?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See the docs:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

The static resources are loaded from `/static`, `/public`, `/resources`, `/META-INF/resources`

If you are packaging your application as a JAR (deploying a .jar), using `src/main/webapp` is not recommended.

You can customize that by overriding the `addResourceHandlers` method in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

```
    @Configuration
    public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
             registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think stating "Using `src/main/webapp` is not recommended" can be misinterpreted by the reader. According to the documentation "Do not use the src/main/webapp directory *if your application will be packaged as a jar*", so you should mention that as well.

Comment: Yes, that line is completely misleading.

Comment: Why spring boot does not work with `src/main/webapp` in jar packing? I was curious because what if we needed to migrate our existing `war` packaged app to Spring boot?

Comment: @akash Totally agree, this is what I am trying to do now for my project.

Comment: on Spring Boot `2.4.x` the default servlet is now disabled, which impacts on loading of these resources. You need `server.servlet.register-default-servlet=true` (or equivalent) in `application.properties`.

Comment: I use spring-boot version 2.3.7 and this solution didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

AS mentioned above, `jar` packaging ignores `webapp` content. If you still want to include the contents inside `webapp` folder, you need to specify this  explicitly in maven `POM.xml` configuration as below -

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources> ...
```