# Should I use `src/main/webapp` to serve static content with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, static-files

The [documentation of Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) states:

> Do not use the src/main/webapp directory if your application will be
>   packaged as a jar.

But surprisingly the [Spring Boot Sample for static web files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static/) is using the `/src/main/webapp` directory. And also [JHipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/tree/master/app/templates/src/main/webapp) is using the `webapp` folder.

So I'm confused. Is the warning in the documentation of Spring Boot outdated? Is it now considered good practice to use `src/main/webapp` to serve static files with Spring Boot jar applications? And if not, what is the recommended practice now when using Spring Boot in a Maven setup?

Comment: the sample app you reference is packaged as a war, not a jar. See the pom: <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: Ok, that explains why the example works. But I thought one of the main selling points of Spring Boot is that it creates a standalone jar file. So the example is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1):

From [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) (emphasis mine):

> **By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext**. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriding the addResourceHandlers method.

In some of my (Maven) projects I am currently using `src/main/resources/static` because it's considered part of the classpath by default and IDEs (like Eclipse) tend to like this.

Answer (score 1):

Be wary because Spring Boot `2.4.x` disables the default servlet (which impacts on loading of `src\main\webapp` and anything else at the root of your WAR file. JAR file packaging is disabled by default but there is a configuration option to all that too - see [Spring boot: configure it to find the webapp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725635/spring-boot-configure-it-to-find-the-webapp-folder#answer-47265550).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22915

The full release notes are here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/12/spring-boot-2-4-0-available-now

Answer (score 0):

hi if i understand your question 
when your are using jar packaging in spring boot
yo will put your resource in META-INF/resources 
and you can use this jar package in other project and call resource ,
you can move webapp to meta-inf directory using maven and gradle build