# Eclipse vs. Spring Boot gives JSP error: Fragment "/js/home.js" was not found at expected path /src/main/webapp/js/home.js

Tags: spring, eclipse, jsp, spring-boot, jar

I have the line

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <%@include file="/js/home.js" %>
```

Which gives the error in title. The JS files are in `/src/main/resources/static/js`. The error goes away if I create `/src/main/webapp/js/home.js`. This answer says `webapp/` is not recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727189/148844. We are using JARs and we are uploading a WAR to AWS via the web console. Eclipse expects `webapp/js/` and Spring Boot expects `resources/static/js`, so which should I use? How do I tell Eclipse how to find the JS file?

```
$ tree
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │   └───static
│   │   │       ├───css
│   │   │       ├───fonts
│   │   │       ├───img
│   │   │       └───js
│   │   └───webapp
│   │       └───WEB-INF
│   │           └───jsp
```

We also have

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Eclipse Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: I changed it to `<script src="/js/home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` for the time being.

Comment: A comment in the answer you linked clarifies, do not use `/src/main/webapp` if you are _packaging_ as as JAR, not strictly *using* JARs. You are packaging as WAR.

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez OK but it says it will silently fail for other tools. If we wish to switch to maybe WebLogic or another servlet container, I would like to make the app as portable as possible without having it silently fail or require lots of code-rework. We are also working on automated deployments from Git so it would no longer be in a WAR/JAR format then (maybe). Basically I want to stick with best, most accepted practices, even if we can get away with it in our special niche circumstance.