# Change default directory structure for spring boot & maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using spring boot with maven project, this has generated a default project structure something like below

> src/main/java
>
> src/main/resources
>
> src/main/webapp
>
> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
>
> src/test/java

But

I want to change/modify it something like this

> src/main/java
>
> src/test/java
>
> *WebContent/webapp*
>
> *WebContent/webapp/WEB-INF*
>
> *WebContent/webapp/Resources*

**Is it possible to do this? (especially webapp directory location)**

Comment: Check the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725635/spring-boot-configure-it-to-find-the-webapp-folder

Comment: Thanks, Let me check. It looks useful